Digikam for exporting virtual gallery (selection)
Will Digikam (or alternatively any of Acdesee, Geeqie, Excire) support a workflow where I select some pictures for export, review the collection as a gallery or slideshow, export the collection and then keep the export metadata (a list of which photos were exported) but not the duplicates (the exported photos).
Currently when I make a selection of photos, I copy them to a separate folder. This leaves me with many folders filled with duplicates.
I use selections to share pictures, by printing them or as a zip-file over we transfer.
The background to this question is that I'm looking to start using a photo-management tool. I'm on OSX but a tool that also works on Windows is a plus, and it absolutely has to manage photo's locally without moving files. It would be cool if tagging worked by editing exif information.
These requirements have led to the shortlist of Digikam, Acdesee, Geeqie and Excire. Now I'm just trying to choose one.

You can check also Adobe Lightroom.

Since you are on OSX you can probably create a folder and link the relevant pictures in it instead of copying them.

If you drag/drop the selected photos to TextEdit on Mac, do you get a list of filepaths to photos you wanted to export? You could then use that list as input for  some script to create a symlinks or aliases to these photos.

@SaaruLindestøkke This is an option, but usually a selection involves an number of cycles of going through the photo's. With filepaths in a textfile there is no easy way of checking  the selection another time and pruning.

If you are looking for a method to sort a batch of photo's and keep a track of where you have used individual images, digikam has several tools that can help.

Rather than copying the files you could use a pick label (flag), colour label,  rating label (star) or keyword tag to indicate which pictures you have selected for your selection. The manual is available online and has a section on Digital Asset Management
The manual suggests schemes for rating images as follows:

Pick Labels used to categorize shots by quality and identify which
item will be Rejected, Pending, or Accepted in your workflow.


...take a moment to establish personal criteria for ranking. Best
practice is to write down your personal match of stars to some
qualitative expression, that will define what you actually mean when
giving 5 stars. Generally there should be much less images rated with
increasing star assignment. A ratio of 3-10 between each level has
proven useful.take a moment to establish personal criteria for
ranking. Best practice is to write down your personal match of stars
to some qualitative expression, that will define what you actually
mean when giving 5 stars. Generally there should be much less images
rated with increasing star assignment. A ratio of 3-10 between each
level has proven useful.
This will help you culling and thinning your collection very efficiently. Or you could define purposes to ratings, like this:
    0 stars for can throw away.
    1 star  for images in quarantine (decide later).
    2 stars for gallery export.
    3 stars for printing.
    4 stars for selling.
    5 stars for have to work on.


Following on from @Peter M's comments below, I've reread the manual and added a bit more context which  clarifies that the scheme above is an alternative way of thinking about using star ratings. My personal use goes something like:
0 stars for rejected, nothing to redeem this travesty
1 star for technically terrible but a unique moment I can't bring myself to bin
2 stars for artistically ok, but too noisy or not as sharp as I want
3 stars technically good, sharp in all the right places
4 stars this weeks favourite, technically and artistically strong
5 stars perfect, nailed on for a world photography award

I've never managed a 5. but I'm still hoping...
You could also use the colour labels to do do something to your own design or create a metadata keyword tag for version and sub tags describing the different version names.
Using these metadata methods it would be possible to quickly search or filter for images that were previously selected for particular reasons without creating endless copies.
Alternatively if you are exporting the same image in different versions darktable has some useful features. In my own workflow I might export my RAW's from Darktable using duplicates (which only duplicates the .xmp sidecar) under different version names. This helps if I want a version to archive, a version for print, a version for social media and a version for sharing via email, all with different colour spaces, compression ratios, resolutions etc.

That star rating seems weird with 5 stars being having to work on the pic.  That means if you have worked on all your pics, then there will be no 5 star pics in your collection.

@Peter M agreed. It would not be my choice, but it's in the manual and I guess illustrates that it does not need to be 1 star OK, 2 stars better, 5 stars perfect which would be the most obvious use (to me at least).

Yeah, it is an interesting take on "star" ratings, but it also seems to be tailored to a professional workflow with 4 stars being selling.  But I also think it shows the limitations of a star rating used in this way.  0 and 1 stars are the only "quality" ratings, while 2 through 5 stars are actually tags that indicate stages of workflow.  It's almost as if the author wanted a 2D criteria with quality being one axis and stages of workflow being the other.
